# Dockerized next app deployed into oci ubuntu redirects to my localhost

Tags: docker

I'm trying to deploy next app into OCI ubuntu machine with docker using the `Dockerfile` example of `next docs`. I built the image and run it on the server and exposed port `3000`

The problem is that when I access the public ip of the server it redirects me to `localhost` of my own host not the server.

Any help please?

The `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN yarn


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME '0.0.0.0'

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Please include the `Dockerfile` in your question.

Comment: Thank you. There are other things that are needed to reproduce your setup. Please share the `package.json` file. The contents of `server.js`  are also relevant. Please share a _stripped down_ version of that file which exhibits this issue. In general it's easier to get help if you provide all of the information required to replicate your setup. 